# Storing Images for Web App

Tags: php, image, mobile, web, storage

I am doing a restaurant **website in PHP and also a mobile site** for the same. *The images of restaurant food products will be same in both*. The images will be uploaded by the restaurant Admin. *That means same image will be used to show in both desktop and mobile site.*

I want to know the best way to store image for this scenario. Currently *I am storing the image inside **uploads** folder of Desktop Application and referring to this in both mobile and desktop sites*, which is not good I think. Can someone suggest a good method with lesser load time which can be used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try and determine the type of browser that access the site.  Save that info in an $_SESSION and then display pictures accordingly to the value stored for that session.  Desktop users see pictures sized to that platform and mobile users for theirs.

Comment: I want to know where to store user uploaded images. Create a common domain for images like i.xyz.com/images  and use this to show images for mobile and desktop website. Or can I store inside Desktop site project like desktopsite.com/images/ and use it for Desktop site and also for mobile site. Or should I use services like Amazon S3.

Comment: I take it that you have different sized images for desktop and mobile. I would save them in different folders, just to make admin around the images a bit easier.